# Adding an image into an .html envelope for signature via REST API

Tags: html, png, docusignapi

I am trying to include an image into the document that I am sending for signature but it will not render. The envelope I am sending is an .HTML file which Docusign then converts to PDF. Does Docusign support `<img/>` elements within an HTML envelope? Anyone have experience with this or know what my issue would be? I have tried the same image as PNG, JPG, and SVG...none of which render. Any feedback is much appreciated.

This is what my image tag looks like (with PNG):

`<img src="./path/to/my/image.png" class="logo" alt="logo"/>`

And what the image "renders" as in the PDF, which is not correct:
[image: docusign pdf image]

Comment: I've got it working when converting the html to a pdf before uploading to docusign. And then uploading it as pdf. Image comes through fine now!

Comment: is the url HTTP or HTTPS? If it's HTTP I don't think it will pull through correctly, but HTTPS should work assuming the address is accessible at the time.

Comment: https isn't working for me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I did not get this to work when uploading an `.html` document to Docusign, what resolved the issue for me was converting the HTML into PDF (using wkhtmltopdf) and then uploading the PDF to Docusign. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Comment: but thats not an intended solution. It should work for html solutions

Comment: I have posted a solution above. I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use a base64 encoded image. That goes fine. I know the question was asked more than a year ago, but just thought to post an answer since I was searching for this and had a hard time finding the solution. You can do it like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

You can get base64 encoding for any image using any of the online services.